# how to register a shortcut key to type a diacritic in icewm?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xdotool, icewm

I am trying to setup shortcut keys to type common diacritics.
I am able to have xdotool type the diacritic in a terminal or from the icewm command bar (or even from gmrun):

`xdotool key Aacute`

But the following keymappings (in icewm keys file) do not work:

```
key "Ctrl+Alt+a"                  xdotool key Aacute
key "Ctrl+Alt+a"                  xdotool --delay 1000 key Aacute
```

Instead, I just see the cursor blink once when I type the shortcut (if in terminal or text editor), but nothing else happens. The following does show a popup, so the key code itself is correct:

```
key "Ctrl+Alt+a"                  zenity --info --text="shortcut works"
```

Does anyone have a way to register the key binding, so that the diacritic is actually typed in the active application?

Comment: diacritics are basically accented characters. Have you considered using the Compose key to provide an accented character?

Comment: Compose key is better than nothing, but compose key is 3 actions for a single letter, a shortcut key would be a single action (of multiple keys) and thus way faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get my original solution to work, so I changed the keyboard mapping instead.
The default us keyboard mapping doesn't have the diacritics I need, but the international version does.
To try it out:

`setxkbmap -layout 'us(intl)'`

But the internation version uses compose by default for certain keys. 
For example, the ' character no longer responds immediately.
So instead I opted to create my own keyboard mapping based on the us keyboard.

I created a new file: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/erik`

```
partial default alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
  include "us"
  include "eurosign(5)"

    key <AC01> { [         a,          A,        aacute,           Aacute ] };
    key <AD03> { [         e,          E,        eacute,           Eacute ] };
    key <AD08> { [         i,          I,        iacute,           Iacute ] };
    key <AD09> { [         o,          O,        oacute,           Oacute ] };
    key <AD07> { [         u,          U,        uacute,           Uacute ] };

    key <RALT>  { type[Group1]="TWO_LEVEL", [ ISO_Level3_Shift, Multi_key ]   };  

    modifier_map Mod5   { <RALT> };
};
```

to have xkb pick up the changes:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`

to try the keyboard mapping:

`setxkbmap -layout erik`

Now alt_gr + [aeiou] should type [áéíóú].

I made the changes permanent by calling the above command on startup using the icewm startup file.
I think it should be possible to select the layout using your distributions keyboard switcher, but I haven't tested this.
Feel free to name the file something else, unless you want to give me the tremendous honour of naming your keyboard mapping after me.
Just be sure to avoid 2 letter codes, because all the default country mappings are so named.

notes:
You can check the other mapping files in the symbols directory for examples.
Some resources for understanding the file format can be found here:
https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/

Answer (score 1):

Using `setxkbmap` or `xmodmap` seems like the right thing to do, but FWIW and FTR I found that the following worked for me after I came across this question. I'm hoping this helps others who want to use `xdotool`.

I have xdotool emulate these keys since I don't have them on my keyboard. Note the use of `&` to run the command in the background so that IceWM can return from handling the hot key and avoid interfering with xdotool.

200 ms is the shortest delay I could use and still have it work reliably. I'm not sure if `--clearmodifiers` makes sense for your use case or not.

```
key "Ctrl+Up"          xdotool sleep 0.2 key --clearmodifiers Page_Up &
key "Ctrl+Down"        xdotool sleep 0.2 key --clearmodifiers Page_Down &
key "Ctrl+Shift+Up"    xdotool sleep 0.2 key --clearmodifiers Home &
key "Ctrl+Shift+Down"  xdotool sleep 0.2 key --clearmodifiers End &
```

Also note that holding down these keys doesn't result in the expected repeating behavior (because IceWM hot keys are not the best choice for this) but that's fine for my purposes.